# Как удалить случайно оставленную мною метку, если с ней не связан ни один вопрос?

Tags: предложение, метки, удаление-метки, создание-метки

Я сперва создал метку [профиль](/questions/tagged/%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%84%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c), но затем решил "переименовать", создал и стал использовать метку [профиль-участника](/questions/tagged/%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%84%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c-%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0). Как мне её удалить? И если это невозможно сделать мною, то я хотел бы запросить данный функционал.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Сама удалится через день примерно.

Comment: Хорошо, если сама удалится, то будет круто. Но было бы ещё лучше, если бы это также можно было бы сделать самому.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov, модераторы вроде могут

Comment: @Grundy но простой пользователь, я полагаю, тоже должен иметь возможность удалять то, что сам и создал и что не используется ни в одном вопросе.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov, интересно с чего бы? :)

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov, зачем, если оно само удалится?

Comment: Модераторы не могут удалять метки. Система сама удалит метку, которая не используется.

Comment: До сих пор метка не удалилась метка.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov, удалилась. По крайней мере, сейчас её нет.